# Current state of Stateful Widget (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

How to get the current state of a Stateful Widget?
I need a variable of my Stateful Widget, so I need the current State of it.

Here is my Stateful Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChoiceQuesionListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String answer;
  const ChoiceQuesionListTile({
    this.answer,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ChoiceQuesionListTileState createState() => _ChoiceQuesionListTileState();
}

class _ChoiceQuesionListTileState extends State<ChoiceQuesionListTile> {
  String _answer;
  bool _validity = false;

  bool get validity => _validity;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _answer = widget.answer;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Checkbox(
            value: _validity,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _validity = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          Text(_answer),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In my another Stateful Widget I create ChoiceQuestionListTile(answer: "test") and after I click on my Checkbox (that is inside of the ChoiceQuestionListTile) I have to submit the values, so thats why I need to get validity.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question with the code you are using or with an example code ?

Comment: This smells of poor or misunderstood code design.  What are you doing that you need the State from your "stateful widget".  And what does the "State" mean?  All the member variables of your state class?

Comment: Sample code please

Comment: @RandalSchwartz i have edited my question and added some code

Comment: @MidhunMP i have edited my question and added some code

Comment: @Mick i have edited my question and added some code

Comment: Something is wrong with your widget, it wont compile in https://dartpad.dev/flutter?

Comment: @Mick I already solved it by just creating a Model that stores String answer and bool validity, and the Stateful widget I was using I have just deleted. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem, happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a callback to get that value back.

```dart
class ChoiceQuesionListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String answer;
  final Function(bool) onSelected;

  const ChoiceQuesionListTile({
    this.answer,
    this.onSelected,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChoiceQuesionListTileState createState() => _ChoiceQuesionListTileState();
}

class _ChoiceQuesionListTileState extends State<ChoiceQuesionListTile> {
  bool _validity = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Checkbox(
            value: _validity,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _validity = value;
              });
              widget.onSelected(value);
            },
          ),
          Text(widget.answer),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When you create the widget pass the callback like:

```dart
ChoiceQuesionListTile(
   answer: 'Test',
   onSelected: (value) {
      print(value);
   },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, you need to make ChoiceQuesionListTile a stateless widget and the parent widget should control the state of the tile. (This is called [lifting state up](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#lifting-state-up)).

Your ChoiceQuestionListTile widget should have a similar implementation as the Checkbox widget:

```
      Checkbox(
        value: _validity,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _validity = value;
          });
        },
      ),
```

1. it should take a `bool value` as *current value* of validity
2. it should take an `ValueChanged<bool> onChanged` callback which will be invoked when the value is changed internally.
3. the parent widget will control what goes in and out of the tile widget.

have a look at [CheckboxListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this Problem by creating the Model that stores String answer and bool validity. I deleted the Stateful Widget and pasted the code of that Stateful Widget in the ListView Builder where I implemented that Statefulwidget.